# Why inserting the number of channels are not working?

Tags: python, channel

```
num_x_train = (x_train.shape[0])
num_x_val = (x_val.shape[0])
num_x_test = (x_test.shape[0])

print("trian data : {}\tlabel : {}".format(x_train_full.shape, y_train_full.shape,img.channel))
print("train data : {}\tlabel : {}".format(x_train.shape, y_train.shape,))
print("val data : {}\tlabel : {}".format(x_val.shape, y_val.shape,))
print("test data : {}\tlabel : {}".format(x_test.shape, y_test.shape,))

num_sample = 5

random_idxs = np.random.randint(6000, size = num_sample)

plt.figure(figsize=(14,8))
for i, idx in enumerate(random_idxs):
  img = x_train_full[idx,:]
  label = y_train_full[idx]

  plt.subplot(1, len(random_idxs), i+1)
  plt.imshow(img)
  plt.title("Index: {}, Label : {}".format(idx, label))

plt.show()`
```

in the print() part, I would like to show the number of channels that are used in the coding. Currently using black and white images.
I tried to edit the code but it didn't work.
How can I solve this problem?

expectation of the result would look like train data : (60000, 28, 28, 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and welcome Jun!

Your img.channel is not printed because there is no placeholder for it in your formatting string below:

```
print("trian data : {}\tlabel : {}".format(x_train_full.shape, y_train_full.shape,img.channel))
```

To have it work, you need to add the necessary 3rd placeholder, like this:

```
print("trian data : {}\tlabel : {}, channels: {}".format(x_train_full.shape, y_train_full.shape, img.channel))
```

If you work with Python 3.6 or higher, you can also use the [f-string formatting](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/python-f-strings-literal-string-interpolation):

```
print(f"trian data : {x_train_full.shape}\tlabel : {y_train_full.shape}, channels: {img.channel}")
```

Hope it helps!